# Where did hot dogs get their name?

Tags: meat, sausages, history

Were they orginally made from real dogs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term "dog" has been used as a synonym for sausage since 1884 and accusations that sausage makers used dog meat to at least 1845.

According to a myth, the use of the complete phrase "hot dog" in reference to sausage was coined by a newspaper cartoonist in 1900, but there were several earlier references, but no specifics on the origination of the phrase.

Comment: http://www.hot-dog.org/culture/hot-dog-history

Answer (score 2):

Thesaurus.com has an [article](http://dictionary.reference.com/slideshows/american-foods#hot-dog) on the name. Their explanation is that the long sausages got compared to dachshunds. With time, people started calling them "dogs" instead of "dachshunds".

They don't list a source for the information, but I hope that, being language experts, they have fact-checked it.